# NuxtJS component - component renders without data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a component that uses fetch to bring data via Axios and return data to render. I am using the store to set/get the data. The component renders with empty data and after debugging I see that data() method is called before fetch() method.
How to fix the problem and bring the data before the component is rendered

here is the component code:

```html
<template>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="500"
  >
    <v-sheet class="pa-4 primary lighten-2">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        label="Search Company Directory"
        dark
        flat
        solo-inverted
        hide-details
        clearable
        clear-icon="mdi-close-circle-outline"
      ></v-text-field>
      <v-checkbox
        v-model="caseSensitive"
        dark
        hide-details
        label="Case sensitive search"
      ></v-checkbox>
    </v-sheet>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-treeview
        :items="items"
        :search="search"
        :filter="filter"
        :open.sync="open"
      >
        <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
          <v-icon
            v-if="item.children"
            v-text="mdi-${item.id === 1 ? 'home-variant' : 'folder-network'}"
          ></v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-treeview>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async fetch(){
        console.log("Hi from Fetch !!!")
        let response = await this.$axios.get('/items/tasks', {baseURL: 'http://localhost:8055'});
        let tasks = response.data.data;
        debugger        

        this.$store.commit('SET_ASSIGNMENTS', tasks);
    },  
    data () {
    debugger
    console.log("data assignments: ", this.$store.state.assignments);
    return {
      items: this.$store.state.assignments,
      open: [1, 2],
      search: null,
      caseSensitive: false,
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filter () {
        return this.caseSensitive
          ? (item, search, textKey) => item[textKey].indexOf(search) > -1
          : undefined
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `data` is pretty much for static values, ones that you can know during the render. In the case of Vuex, use a helper like `mapState` or wrap your whole state into a `computed`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

Answer (score 1):

For this I use vuex this way:

```
const appStore = {
  state () {
    return {
      data: [],
    }
  },
  getters: {
    data(state) {
        return state.data
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_ASSIGNMENTS(state, payload) {
        state.data = payload
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async getData({ commit }, {fromDate, toDate}) {
        let response = await this.$axios.get('/items/tasks', {baseURL: 'http://localhost:8055'});
        let tasks = response.data.data;
        commit("SET_ASSIGNMENTS", tasks);
    }
  }
}

export default appStore
```

Component code is like this:

```
<template>
     . . .   
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    name: "MyComponent",
    components: {
       . . .
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        data: 'data'
    })
    },
    mounted(){
      this.getData();
    },
    methods: {
      getData() {
        this.$store.dispatch('getData')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not reactive, you can create a computed property that returns your `items`

ex:`reactiveItems() {return this.items}`